# Play all but one + hand limit zero + draw one = stalemate?

Tags: fluxx

If the current rules include "Hand Limit 0", "Play all but 1", and "Draw 1", doesn't the game just kind of... stall?

This has never actually happened but thinking about it, we figured we'd probably have to count that as a case of "everyone loses" and just start over! :)

Comment: Interesting; hadn't heard of "play all but 1"; Fluxx keeps changing with new editions!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Future printings have been revised to:

> Play all but 1 of your cards. If you started with no cards in your hand and only drew 1, draw an extra card.

https://faq.looneylabs.com/archives/faq-tags/play-all-but-1

That avoids this situation.